# Proving a linear transformation is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

Correct me if I'm mistaken, but a linear transformation is continuous if it is bounded, correct?

> Let $T: (\mathbb{R^n}, \left\|\cdot\right\|_1) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R^m}, \left\|\cdot\right\|_1)$ be a linear transformation. Show that $T$ is continuous. Note that in this case, $$\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|_1\leq 1} \|Tx\|_1.$$

Thus, we have $\|x\|_1 \leq 1$ so that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i| \leq 1$. Thus, $$\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|_1\leq 1} \|Tx\|_1 = \sup_{\|x\|_1\leq 1} \left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{1i} x_i\right| + \dotsb + \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{mi} x_i\right|\right).$$

However, from this point we cannot say that $$\tag{**}\|T\| \leq \left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{1i}\right| + \dotsb + \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{mi}\right|\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} t_{ji}.$$
This was my original idea, but I believe this is incorrect as $\|x\|_1 \leq 1 \nrightarrow (^{**})$, correct?

If this is true, how do I go about finishing the proof?

**edit:** I'm now seeing a statement in my textbook that says the following:

> If $S$ is a metric space, if $a_{11}, ..., a_{mn}$ are real continuous functions on $S$, and if, for each $p\in S$, $A_p$ is the linear transformation of $R^n$ into $R^m$ whose matrix has entries $a_{ij}(p)$, then the mapping $p \rightarrow A_p$ is a continuous mapping of $S$ into $L(R^n, R^m)$.

What exactly are $S$ and $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to think in terms of a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and how $T$ acts on that basis rather than working component by component.

Let $\{e_i: 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\lvert \lvert T(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i) \rvert \rvert = \lvert \lvert \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i T(e_i) \rvert \rvert \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert \lambda_i \rvert \cdot \lvert \lvert T(e_i) \rvert \rvert \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert \lambda_i \rvert \max \lvert \lvert T(e_i) \rvert \rvert \\ = \max \lvert \lvert T(e_i) \rvert \rvert \cdot  \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert \lambda_i \rvert \bigg )= \max \lvert \lvert T(e_i) \rvert \rvert \cdot \lvert \lvert \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i \rvert \rvert_1$$

which shows that $T$ is continuous since if we express $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i$ and $\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert_1 \leq 1$ then the above gives $\lvert \lvert Tx \rvert \rvert \leq \max \lvert \lvert T(e_i) \rvert \rvert$ so we get that $T$ is bounded.

Edit: To answer the question added in your edit, A metric space $S$ is a set equipped with a function $d:S^2 \to [0,\infty)$ giving the distance between two points satisfying $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$, $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ and the triangle inequality - $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. A norm induces a metric by setting $d(x,y) = \lvert \lvert x-y \rvert \rvert$ but not all metrics arise this way.

Comment: I follow everything until the last inequality - why is that true?

Also, why does this prove continuity? Sorry, it's just such an odd concept and I'm fairly new to it!

Comment: Ah, so would $S$ in this situation be $(\mathbb{R^n}, \left\|\cdot\right\|_1)$?

Comment: I've added to the answer to hopefully clarify the inequality and why we get continuity. The statement you added in the edit doesn't seem to be applicable here to me. You want to show that a particular linear operator is continuous. The statement tells you that a map that sends elements of a metric space to linear operators is continuous, not that any of the operators are themselves continuous. (although those operators do end up being continuous by the result in the question.)

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem. Your edited answer has definitely cleared it up - I suppose I just wasn't sure what a suitable bound for $||Tx||$ was. So $||Tx||$ is bounded by the maximum of $T$ at its standard basis - but how do we know that max$||T(e_i)||$ exists?

Comment: Yes, it's important we use this basis because the norm $\lvert \lvert \cdot \rvert \rvert_1$ is expressed in terms of descriptions of vectors with respect to that basis.